# Ruleset level logging in Rule Execution Server

Tags: logging, websphere, rules, ibm-odm

I have a requirement for logging ruleset request and response fields. I have 30 ruleapps and each rule app contains 1 ruleset. So, totally I have 30 rulesets. Each ruleset belongs to each client project.

If I want to log the request and response fields of rulesets I need to implement my own logging in all the 30 ruleapps xoms by using log4j third party libraries.

But I am looking for a solution in such a way that, If I do any customisations to RES, then I will own my logging standards or common logging for all other rule apps request and response.

The solution should eliminate logging dependency in all the ruleapps.

Any suggestions or can we achieve this way of logging in IBM ODM.

Answer (score -1):

you can create your own RuleObserver, use a logging framework in the observer implemented methods. Example :

```
MyObserver implements EngineObserver, RuleEngineObserver
```

In order to use this observer, you can set it in an initial rule of your flow.

```
ruleflow.addObserver(observer) or engine.addObserver(observer)
```

source :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.10.x/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/executing_decision_topics/tsk_exec_get_notif_de.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27884593)

Comment: thanks for the comment.
I added the example.